# Jquery Reading Table from $.get response

Tags: jquery, get

I guys, I am having some trouble figuring out how to read data from a table that is coming from a response. I have tried a few methods I read on this site, however when I get the data from $.get I kept getting an error that I could not getElementsByID from var table when trying to get "".

Here is how I can getting the data, is there any easy way to cycle through the rows and cells?

```
$.get( URL, function(data) 
{
     checkPage(data);
});

function checkPage(data)
{
     var table = $('#ctlgrid', $(data)).html();
}
```

Comment: Need to know more details to help you. What is your get retrieving? Also are you sure you should be adding the data to a jquery object? I think more likely you want to sort the data then use the html function to add the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think more likely your code should look like this:

```
$.get(URL, function(data){
    var table = $('#ctlgrid').html(data);
});
```

I cleaned up the extra function and moved it inside the get. To create DOM, you need to put an argument in the html function. Otherwise it will return the html contained within that DOM id.

Note: You will want to make your table variable global if you plan on editing it outside of that function.

As for cycling through the results, depending on how your table looks and what your get is retrieving:

```
$('#ctrlgrid td').each(function(){
    $(this).//Do something here with that data.
});
```

The each function has additional parameters it can take depending on your needs. See [this](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for examples.

### Table example

```
$.get(URL, function(data){
    var table = $('#ctlgrid').html(data);
    var rows = table.children('tr');
    rows.each(function(){
        var cells = $(this).children('td');
        //Do something with the cells.
    });
});
```

Comment: i just tried this using .html(data):
    var table =   $('#ctlgrid').html(data);
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),i, j, cells, customerId;

but I ended up with this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getElementsByTagName'

Comment: It is easier to use jQuery to find the cells. To retrieve the cells of the table that you insert you should use `.children('td')`. To get rows it would be `.children('tr')`.

Comment: It might also be safe to set the html and then create a new jQuery objects for the table using `var table = $('#ctlgrid table')`, but this depends on how your dom is structured.